# Move an image down with html

Tags: html, css, image

I'm having a problem moving down an image with html, here is part of my code. The image ends up being right next to the hyperlink and I want it to be right below it. Sorry if this seems like a silly question this is my first time coding and I am trying to create a website. Thanks!

```html
<body>

  <h1 style="text-align:center;font-size:30px"><a href="bluetongueskink.html" style:color:#333>Blue Tongue Skink</a>


    <img src=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Tiliqua_scincoides_scincoides.jpg/1200px-Tiliqua_scincoides_scincoides.jpg alt="HTML tutorial" style="width:300px;height:200px;border:0;" <body>

</body </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is just **very** malformed (extra `<body>` tags and missing closing `</h1>`, missing end `>` in `<img...` and the third `<body`, missing opening `<html>`, and so on...):

```html
<html>

<body>

  <h1 style="text-align:center;font-size:30px">
    <a href="bluetongueskink.html" style:color:#333>Blue Tongue Skink</a>
  </h1>

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Tiliqua_scincoides_scincoides.jpg/1200px-Tiliqua_scincoides_scincoides.jpg" alt="HTML tutorial" style="width:300px;height:200px;border:0;" />

</body>

</html>
```